# Angular2 - How do I delay initial load until service completes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 RC6 application and I need to defer loading pages until after some functionality is executed.

I have a service that determines the URI for the webApi.  I need the application to wait until this URL is determined before it tries to load any data.  If I hide the main application in app.component, with an *ngIf, I get routing errors because the router outlet does not exists.

Before RC5/6 I manually bootstrapped the application after the service get's the URI.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code but you can try to use Observable or Promise in your service and then wait until it completes.

Comment: But I can't bootstrap when it completes.  In RC6 you add the bootstrap to NgModule and I don't know how to make it conditional.

Comment: Why do you want to defer the loading of the entire page (templates)? Aren't you just waiting for data from an API?

Comment: Yes.  But there are API calls throughout the application.  With deep URL linking the user could be going to any page and using any API.  I would have to put a check on all of them.  We have already built it using the process of bootstraping when it's ready and I just need to move it to RC6.  Plus, I don't want another manual task we have to do to do any call.  It seems cleaner if we just wait until it's ready to bootstrap it  - or to load any page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517961/resolve-a-value-before-activating-a-route-in-angular-2/36518012#36518012 (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function/38425489#38425489)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the router you can use [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html), [`canActivateChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivateChild-interface.html).

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards
- [Resolve a value *before* activating a route in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517961/resolve-a-value-before-activating-a-route-in-angular-2/36518012#36518012)
- [Angular2 canActivate() calling async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function/38425489#38425489)

For loading once before app initialization you can use `APP_INITIALIZER` as explained in [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614)